# Geometry node material works in cycles lookdev and eevee but not in cycles rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

Following [Hell FX Learn's Shield Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=no1zkwhwAHs), I slightly modified the nodes so that the material would change if inside the mask object. I get my desired result when in the lookdev mode of cycles or the rendered mode of eevee. The effect breaks when looking at it through Cycles rendered view mode.

Node setup:
[image]
Result in lookdev:
[image]
Result in rendered viewmode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally **duplicated your mesh** and what you see is a "glitch" effect of two coplanar faces. When you join the two *Set Material* Nodes, the *Join Geometry* Node might receive twice the geometry, even though they have different Material selection sets.

[image]

My guess would be that the **ray tracer** from the cycles engine shows the glitch, while eevvee and lookdev are not so... erm, picky about it.

Comment: I deleted the join geometry and moved the set material to damaged shield after the set to shield with their corresponding selections. Now, there is no duplicate geometry/glitch. Thanks for the help!